# "access" uefi in ubuntu focal after secure boot update CANNOT PUSH DELETE DURING BOOT

Tags: boot, bios

"access" uefi in ubuntu focal after secure boot update CANNOT PUSH DELETE DURING BOOT.

before receiving the "secure boot" update. i was actually able to access my asus bios and eufi gui.

alls you have to do for asus models is push delete once after the system makes the boot audio sound and it will enter.

now it COMPLETELY IGNORES the delete key. is that what you call secure boot?!

ive tried looking for how to access the "boot into eufi" mode for ubuntu focal for 3 hours now.

im pissed as hell.

may have just found it. after 5 hours of searching. there needs to be a new ubuntu help page with a title "boot to eufi in ubuntu after secure boot update"

sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup

if that command is correct in terminal i WONT be back. otherwise ill come back and say it didnt work lol.

Comment: Try a hard reset of your laptop.  Try these suggestions from ASUS:  https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1032747/  I know it's not that it won't power on, but sometimes the reset helps other issues as well.

Comment: did your advice, it did clean up the cmos a tiny bit and took a few extra seconds booting,pushed delete every 1 seconds after i heard the boot sound and repeated even after the bios screen appeared and left and it didnt even blink at me, just went straight back into the broken ubuntu install im using right now..